# Java Scanner File

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner to read a .csv file.
The file is in the same directory and the .java files, however it can't seem to find the file.
What can I do to fix this issue?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("database.csv"));
```

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention that I need to use the Scanner package because in the next line I use a delimiter.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("database.csv"));
scanner.useDelimiter(",|\r|\n");
```

Also I am working in IntelliJIDEA

So here is the full code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class City
{
public String name; // The name of the city
public String cont; // The continent of the city
public int relTime; // Time relative to Hobart (eg. -14 for New York)
public boolean dst; // Does the city use DST?
public boolean valid; // Does the city exist?
Date currDate;

City(){}; // Default constructor
City(String name, String cont, int relTime)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.cont = cont;
    this.relTime = relTime;
    valid = verify();

    if(valid)
    {
        currDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (3600000 * relTime));
    }
}

City(String name, String cont, int relTime, int dstStartDay, int dstEndDay)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.cont = cont;
    this.relTime = relTime;
    valid = verify();

    if(valid)
    {
        currDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (3600000 * relTime));
        // Is DST in effect?
        if(currDate.after(new Date(currDate.getYear(), 3, dstStartDay, 2, 0)) &&
                currDate.before(new Date(currDate.getYear(), 11, dstEndDay, 2, 0)))
        {
            // It is... so
            relTime--;
        }
    }
}

private boolean verify()
{
    valid = false;

    try
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("\\src\\database.csv"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(",|\r|\n");
        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String curr = scanner.next();
            String next = new String();
            if(scanner.hasNext())
                next = scanner.next();
            if(curr.contains(cont) && next.contains(name))
                return true;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Are the .class files in the same directory as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you put the csv file with the source code together, you can't new File directly, you can try,

```
    InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("database.csv");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(resourceAsStream);
    scanner.useDelimiter(",|\r|\n");
```

Comment: this worked perfectly except i used URL database = this.getClass().getResource("database.csv");  Thanks :)

Comment: Strange, I would swear that that first line was directly part of my answer, and I don't even see an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

When creating or reading a relative file, the path is relative to the specified `user.dir`.  In eclipse, this is often the root of your project.

You can print out the `user.dir` as follows:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

This is where the program is looking for the `database.csv` file.  Either add the file to this directory or use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Add the entire path of the file starting from the root folder of the project .

for eg.

Test is my project name in Eclipse. So i should be writing

`File csvFile = new File("src\\database.csv");`

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't make any difference. still didn't compile

Answer (score 0):

You should not keep files within the directory that also contain the class files. If you do, you should not access them as a file, but as a resource, and they should be copied to the folder or `.jar` containing your compiled `.class` files. If the file is only used by one class in the `.jar` you should probably be using `this.getClass().getResource("database.csv");`.

A disadvantage is that you cannot *write* to resources. If you want to do this I would strongly recommend not to use the source folder for the database file. Instead use a configurable location within the system (e.g. the current working folder).